# How to show "show more" button when text has ellipsis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ellipsis

I have searched on Google and here on SO before posting this question.
I have found several solution to my problem, but none of them fits my needs.

Here is my code: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vb0y4ZCLKyiXlClXuhBk)

```
    <div *ngIf="description.length > 200" class="ui mini compact buttons expand">
        <button class="ui button" (click)="showMore($event)">Show more</button>
    </div>
```

The "show more" button appears only if text length exceeds 200 characters.
As you can see it seems to be a nice solution.

```
showMore(event: any) {
    $(event.target).text((i, text) => { return text === "Show more" ? "Show less" : "Show more";    });
    $(event.target).parent().prev().find('.detail-value').toggleClass('text-ellipsis');
}
```

Anyway I could have a text that is not 200 characters long and that doesn't fit the SPAN element, then it has the ellipsis but the "show more" button doesn't appear.

[image]

How can I make my solution work in any case? Do you know a workaround or a best solution to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit with a possible solution:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {ElementRef,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="ui segment detail-container" (window:resize)="checkOverflow(span)">
      <span class="title-container" role="heading">User details</span>
      <div class="detail-group">
        <div class="detail-element">
          <span class="detail-label">Name</span>
          <span class="detail-value">John</span>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-element">
          <span class="detail-label">Surname</span>
          <span class="detail-value">Smith</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="detail-group">
        <div class="detail-element">
          <span class="detail-label">Description</span>
          <span #span class="detail-value text-ellipsis">{{description}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ui mini compact buttons expand">
            <button  *ngIf="checkOverflow(span) && showMoreFlag" class="ui button" (click)="showMore($event)">Show more</button>
            <button  *ngIf="!showMoreFlag" class="ui button" (click)="showMore($event)">Show less</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['src/app.css']
})



export class App implements OnInit {
  description: string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit a ';
  showMoreFlag:boolean = true;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.overflowOcurs = this.checkOverflow(this.el.nativeElement);
  }

  showMore(event: any) {
        this.showMoreFlag = !this.showMoreFlag;
        $(event.target).parent().prev().find('.detail-value').toggleClass('text-ellipsis');
    }

    checkOverflow (element) {
    if (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight ||
        element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Plunker working properly:

https://plnkr.co/edit/HCd6ds5RBYvlcmUtdvKr

Comment: This could be the fix for my problem, anyway it is not what I was looking for.

Comment: then what is you are looking for? if you explain me may i can help you!

Comment: I'm looking for a way to show the "show more" button when ellipsis occurs, not on characters length.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work if you resize the page :(

Comment: that's easy to resolv. i edited, you can check the result.

Comment: Ehm... now it doesn't work when you load the first time the page with long text...

Answer (score 0):

I Recommend using the "ng2-truncate".

With this component, you can truncate your codes with length or word count or something else.

I hope this component help you.

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/d3JiQCw756OEjS0HkVuY)

[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-truncate)

Comment: length or word? What about lines?

Comment: @smartmouse. it doesn't support lines but it supports max length or word count filter. {{ "abcdefghijkl" | truncate : 3 }} => abc...  or  {{ "abcd ef gh" | words : 2 }} => abcd ef..

Comment: Then it is not what I'm looking for. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Go to this link  [ng2-truncate-source](https://github.com/yellowspot/ng2-truncate-demo) and clone the source code, then change the separator for supporting lines.

Comment: If I could do that I didn't have the need to create a question here :)